# julia: type definition contains variable length array

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I'd like to define in Julia a composite type which contains a variable length array of another composite type. It's better explained by an example. Let's say I have the type

```
type p 
    c::Int
    p() = new(0)
end
```

which I don't really care about. The problem is when I try to define the type

```
type pp 
   len::Int
   arr::Array{p}(1, len)
end
```

Obviously I get an error like "len not defined" and I don't know how to fix it. Moreover, how should I define then the constructor of type `pp`? I'm new to Julia and I'm not even sure if what I'm asking is actually possible.

Comment: you can also use [FixedSizeArrays.jl](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/FixedSizeArrays.jl) to ensure the `arr` is of length `len`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The things that go on the right-hand side of the `::` need to be types.  The expression `Array{p}(1, len)` isn't a type; it actually *creates an array*:

```
julia> len = 3
       Array{p}(1, len)
1×3 Array{p,2}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef
```

It's uninitialized, but you can see that it's an array itself (and not the type of an array).  Its type is simply `Array{p,2}`.  So the minimal fix for your example is simply:

```
type pp 
   len::Int
   arr::Array{p,2}
end
```

That's not really what you want, though.  You probably just need a *vector* of `p` (and not a row matrix, which is what `Array{p}(1,len)` will create).  Also note that Julia's arrays are very full-featured.  You don't need to keep track of the length yourself; the arrays do that already.

So I'd probably write a `PP` type like this:

```
immutable PP
    arr::Vector{p} # Vector{p} is an alias for Array{p, 1}
end
PP(len::Int) = PP(Vector{p}(len))
```